# Compare and Extract elements of 2 Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have 2 `String` Arrays:

`let a = ["jan", "feb", "jun"]`

`let b = ["jan", "may", "feb"]`

I need to check which elements of the `a` array are not in `b` array and store the results in an array called `c`.

I tried to achieve that using this extension:

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable {
    func difference(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        let thisSet = Set(self)
        let otherSet = Set(other)
        return Array(thisSet.symmetricDifference(otherSet))
    }
}
```

but the result it gives me are the difference between the two arrays (ie "may", "jun") whereas I ONLY need the elements from `a` array that are NOT in the `b` array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to make both things into sets, only one of them. One operand needs to be merely iterated (for which `Sequence` is sufficient), and one needs to have fast `contains` performance (for which `Set` is necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract b from a

```
return Array(otherSet.subtracting(thisSet))
```

---

```
let a = ["jan", "feb", "jun"]

let b = ["jan", "may", "feb"]

print(b.difference(from: a)) // jun
```

Comment: Strictly spoken you are subtracting `a` from `b` 

Comment: and it's what should be done when subtracting b from a result will be jun

Answer (score 3):

You want to *subtract* b from a

```
return Array(thisSet.subtracting(otherSet))
```

Alternatively

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable {
    func difference(from other: [Element]) -> [Element] {
        var temp = self
        temp.removeAll{ other.contains($0) }
        return temp
    }
}
```

Comment: this will give the reverse

Comment: *...which elements of the `a` array are not in `b`* is `jun`

Comment: it gives `may` while it should give `jun`

Comment: It depends on the usage: `a.difference(from: b)` returns `jun` 

Comment: the other alternative isn't efficient as using `Set` specially  when array  contain duplicates

Comment: @Sh_Khan Are you sure? The alternative removes also duplicates and is twice as fast as the `Set` solution (tested with 100000 iterations).

Comment: nope tested it with the above arrays with Set took `0.0004400014877319336` while with `removeAll` took `0.003370046615600586` with `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`

Comment: *Tested it* how? In a playground? In a project? In an `XCTestCase`? Debug or Release scheme? The results can be totally different. My test was in an `XCTestCase` with Release scheme (which is the most lifelike).